# tikz: curley brace in a non-parallel plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I am trying to denote some lengthes in a three dimensional tikz figure.
But the result looks weird because the curley braces are not properly transformed.
The `transform shape` option (which does the trick for the labels) has no effect on the braces.
I have also tried to replace the brces by arrows but that is not much better because the arrow tips are not transformed either.

How can I draw curley braces or arrows in a plane which is not parallel to the paper?

```
\documentclass[border=.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\mirror}{\scalebox{-1}[1]}

\tikzset{%
    % changing the axis to point in the directions that I am used to from school:
    % x-axis pointing toward the reader,
    % y-axis pointing right and
    % z-axis pointing up
    % using the same lengthes as TikZ' default settings specified in it's documentation on page 134
    3D/.style={
        x={(-3.85mm, -3.85mm)},
        y={(1cm, 0cm)},
        z={(0cm, 1cm)},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3D]
    \newcommand{\width}{2}
    \newcommand{\height}{1}

    \newcommand{\axislength}{2}
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (\axislength,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,\axislength,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\axislength) node[above] {$z$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0, transform shape]
        \newcommand{\distance}{.5em}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(-\width, \height);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (\distance, 0) -- node[right]{\mirror{$h$}} ++(0, \height);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={brace}] (0,0) ++(0, \height) ++(0, \distance) -- node[above]{\mirror{$w$}} ++(-\width, 0);
%       \draw[<->] (0,0) ++(.5em, 0) -- node[right]{\mirror{$h$}} ++(0, \height);
%       \draw[<->] (0,0) ++(0, \height) ++(0, .5em) -- node[above]{\mirror{$w$}} ++(-\width, 0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command that transforms low level pgf stuff is called `\pgflowlevelsynccm`. It is to be used with care. You can use it here at the end of the scope, so that its effects won't go beyond this scope. Note also that your `\mirror` command can be replaced by the pgf key `xscale=-1` (and `tikz` loads `graphicx` anyway).

```
\documentclass[border=.2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\mirror}{\scalebox{-1}[1]}

\tikzset{%
    % changing the axis to point in the directions that I am used to from school:
    % x-axis pointing toward the reader,
    % y-axis pointing right and
    % z-axis pointing up
    % using the same lengthes as TikZ' default settings specified in it's documentation on page 134
    3D/.style={
        x={(-3.85mm, -3.85mm)},
        y={(1cm, 0cm)},
        z={(0cm, 1cm)},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3D]
    \newcommand{\width}{2}
    \newcommand{\height}{1}

    \newcommand{\axislength}{2}
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (\axislength,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,\axislength,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[gray, ->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,\axislength) node[above] {$z$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0, transform shape]
        \newcommand{\distance}{.5em}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(-\width, \height);
        \pgflowlevelsynccm
        \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (\distance, 0) -- 
        node[left,xscale=-1]{$h$} ++(0, \height);
        \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (0,0) ++(0, \height) 
        ++(0, \distance) -- node[above,xscale=-1]{$w$} ++(-\width, 0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I would use an orthographic projection and a few abbreviations. This allows one to produce the mandatory animation.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,declare function={w=4;h=2;a=4;}]
 \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-1.5*a,-0.5*a) rectangle (1.5*a,1.2*a);
    \draw[gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (a,0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
    \draw[gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,a,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,a) node[above] {$z$};

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0, transform shape]
        \newcommand{\distance}{.5em}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle ++(-w,h);
        \pgflowlevelsynccm
        \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (\distance, 0) -- 
        node[left,xscale=-1]{$h$} ++(0, h);
        \draw[thick,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (0,0) ++(0, h) 
        ++(0, \distance) -- node[above,xscale=-1]{$w$} ++(-w, 0);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]